# Using XY Graph as Control

Tags: labview

What I want to do is using a XY Graph as an user input control that gives me x and y values at the same time. I was able to switch the XY Graph from indicator to control in the block diagram but there is no effect at runtime.

No data is coming out from the XY Graph.

To get the data from the XY Graph I use a "Index Array" Block and an "Unbundle By Name" block to unbundle the first elment to X and Y coords.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of the graph control is simply what appears in it. It makes no sense to use that as a control. If you want to know where the click was, you should use a mouse down event and convert the coords to XY using an invoke node, like so:

[image: Graph Click Coordinates]

Of course, you can use the mouse down event on any kind of control (like a table, for instance), so you don't need a graph specifically for something like that, unless the scales provide you with a convenient UI.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer. I use it with the XY Graph because of the scales. I use the XY Graph UI to simulate an analog joystick to control the NI Robotic Starter Kit.